# $_POST retorna Undefined index

Tags: php

Bom, eu estou tentando fazer um sistema de login, porém o meu $_POST retorna erro "Undefined index" e em todo lugar eu encontro a mesma coisa e mesmo assim da erro.

Html:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">


<div id="login-columns">
    <div id="login-column-1">
        <label for="credentials-email">Email</label>
        <input tabindex="2" type="text" name="credentials.username" id="credentials-email" value="">
    </div>

    <div id="login-column-2">
        <label for="credentials-password">Senha</label>
        <input tabindex="3" type="password" name="credentials.password" id="credentials-password">
    </div>

    <div id="login-column-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <a href="#" tabindex="4" class="button" id="credentials-submit"><b></b><span>Login</span></a>
    </div>...
```

E o php: `echo $_POST['credentials.username'];`

pra mim não tem nenhum erro, só que mesmo assim ele não retorna o valor da input

Comment: Nunca vi um ponto sendo usado como separador nesse tipo de situação... e se trocar por `credentials-username`?

Comment: Ele troca automaticamente o ponto pra underscore

Comment: Testa aí fazer um foreach criando um novo array onde você substitui (pode ser com str_replace) o underscore por um ponto. E depois coloca $_GET = $seu_novo_array.

Comment: Não entendi, como assim usar o foreach pra converter o . em _?

Comment: Para pegar o valor faça como @ZebraDoMal falou use `$_POST['credentials_username']` pode testar no submit.php dando um `print_r($_POST);` assim verá as chaves do array.

Comment: Funcionou :D Vlw.

Comment: Cara, tu tem duas opções, ou faz o que te disse com foreach, ou usa credentials_username.

Comment: Como eu escrevi lá em cima, o php converte o ponto logo pra underscore. Você pode continuar usando o ponto lá no get, mas aí você precisa fazer um novo array onde você substitua o underscore por um ponto e depois atribua ao $_GET o valor do seu novo array.

Comment: No Post eu tive que por _ porém no Input continuou . assim como o ZebraDoMal e o perdeu falou

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isso funciona:

```
 <form action="go2.php" method="post">
 <input type=text name="valor.test.op" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
```

E no lado do PHP

```
 <?php

 echo $_POST['valor_test_op'];

?>
```

Mas mesmo se esta certo, acho o melhor e evitar os pontos no nome, em HTML

Comment: Peter, eu já consegui porém não entendo o porque de ter que se evitar o . (ponto) no Html?